# Getting incorrect LineMetrics (java.awt.font.LineMetrics) in RHEL

Tags: java, fonts, java-8, awt, rhel

I am getting incorrect LineMetrics (java.awt.font.LineMetrics) value (ascent -240, descent 240 and leading 240) when running in RHEL but getting correct value when running in Windows (ascent 10.053711, descent 2.1972656 and leading 0.32714844).

JDK Version: jdk1.8.0_51

OS: RHEL, fedora 7.3 //Getting incorrect value here

OS: Windows 10 //Getting correct value here

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(700, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB); 
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics(); 
Font font = new Font("SansSerif",Font.PLAIN, 10); 
LineMetrics metrics = font.getLineMetrics("ABCxyz", g2.getFontRenderContext()); 
System.out.println("Metrics: "); 
System.out.println("\tAscent: " + metrics.getAscent()); 
System.out.println("\tDescent: " + metrics.getDescent()); 
System.out.println("\tHeight: " + metrics.getHeight()); 
System.out.println("\tLeading: " + metrics.getLeading());
```

Comment: BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(700, 500, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
Font font = new Font("SansSerif",Font.PLAIN, 10);
LineMetrics metrics = font.getLineMetrics("ABCxyz", g2.getFontRenderContext());
System.out.println("Metrics: ");
System.out.println("\tAscent: " + metrics.getAscent());
System.out.println("\tDescent: " + metrics.getDescent());
System.out.println("\tHeight: " + metrics.getHeight());
System.out.println("\tLeading: " + metrics.getLeading());

Answer (score 0):

Installed ttf file in the underlying OS was corrupt because of that I was getting incorrect metrics.